# Вопросы по алгоритму Хаффмана

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Для построения дерева Хаффмана я использовал `list<keyvaluepair<string, int>> tree`. Есть несколько вопросов. Пишу на C#

1. Мы должны всегда начнинать из корня. Кодируя первый символ, мы прослеживаем вверх по дереву все повороты ветвей и если мы делаем левый поворот, то запоминаем 0-й бит, и аналогично 1-й бит для правого поворота. Как именно в `list<keyvaluepair<string, int>> tree` реализовать, что мы двигались вправо или влево?
2. Что можно использовать для запоминания и кодирования битов?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте подходящие структуры данных. В данном случае удобно описать класс узла дерева, с двумя потомками и стоимостью. Построение дерева просто реализуется с использованием [очереди с приоритетом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC).